# Hide statusbar, navigationbar without resize content

Tags: java, android, statusbar

I use below code to hide/unhide statusbar/navigationbar.

```
    public void hideSystemUI() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}

public void showSystemUI() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);


}
```

When the statusbar/navigationbar show or hide then main content resize (check this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11OnTSWBkNnn2PJ3_O0t-IWuregmiNHYW/view?usp=sharing), how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code to hide status bar

```
fun hideStatBar(activity: Activity)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        var window = activity.window
        if (window != null)
        {
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        }
    }
}
```

Method to display the status bar

```
    fun displayStatBar(activity: Activity)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            var window = activity.window
            if (window != null)
            {
                window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
                window.statusBarColor = activity.getColor(R.color.primary_dark)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code is not for my case. I need to show and hide status bar and nagivationbar without resize content. Did you watch my video?